# 405 Method Not Allowed on ASP.NET 5 WebApi OPTIONS preflight

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I am trying to integrate a CORS policy on my app.
I need to use two policies for the purpose, so I followed instructions on [Enable CORS with Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enable-cors-with-attributes) and did the following. For the record, I wrapped CORS configuration in an extension and I am loading the whitelisted endpoints from configuration.

```
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureCors(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return serviceCollection
                .AddCors(cors => cors.AddPolicy(CORS_POLICY_STRICT, policy =>
                    policy
                        .WithOrigins()
                        .WithMethods("POST")
                        .WithHeaders("Authorization")
                ))
                .AddCors(cors =>
                    cors.AddPolicy(CORS_POLICY_FE_API, policy =>
                        policy
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .WithOrigins(GetFrontEndOrigins(configuration))
                    ))
            ;
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

           app
            .UseHttpsRedirection()
            .UseRouting()
            .UseCors()
            .UseAuthentication()
            .UseAuthorization()
            .UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); })
            ;
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .ConfigureCors(Configuration)
            .AddControllers()
            ;
    }
```

`CORS_POLICY_STRICT` is supposed to be a policy for BE-2-BE calls, while the `CORS_POLICY_FE_API` must enlist localhost and prod+dev FE microservices URLs.

I annotated controllers with `[EnableCors(<POLICY_NAME_CONST>)]` where appropriate.

My problem here is that the application starts without errors, Swagger works, but I can't even run a preflight request in cUrl/PowerShell, neither invoke code from Angular app deployed on localhost at another port (4200, the usual).

Picking up any API URL that is annotated with `EnableCorsAttribute`

```
> Invoke-RestMethod -Method Options -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/secure/SomeController/someMethod" -Headers @{"Access-Control-Request-Method"="POST";"Access-Control-Request-Headers"="X-Requested-With"}

$ curl -X OPTIONS "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/secure/SomeController/someMethod" -i
```

both return 405 Method Not Allowed

What is wrong with that?

I also tried to replace the simple `UseCors()` invocation with two calls to `UseCors(string)` each with one of the policy keys. Only the policy name was the argument as I will configure the policies from the services.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually it worked because I had configured an unwanted space in `http://localhost :4200` as one of the allowed origins